# How to center form in all browsers and all mobile devices

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

Hi everyone I have a login form to center this form from top-bottom and left-right I have used  transform: translate(-50%,-50%); it is working fine in chrome, safari, firefox in mobile as well in desktop. but its not working well in **opera browser** I have also added webkit for opera browser.

Here is my [demo to play with css](https://jsfiddle.net/pawh90rg/)
here is html code

```
<div class="container"> 
                <div class="login-form-section">
                    <form class="login-form">
                        <h1 class="login-text">Login</h1>
                        <input type="email" class="input-lg form-control login-input" placeholder="Email" required="" autofocus="">
                        <input type="password" class="form-control login-input input-lg" placeholder="Password" required="">
                        <button class="btn btn-lg btn-yellow-submit btn-block" type="submit">
                        Login
                        </button>
                        <a class="forgot-pass-link" href="forgot-password.html"><span class="f-link">Forgot Password</span></a>
                        <a href="order.html" class="register-link"><span class="r-link">Register and Subscribe</span></a>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
```

and my css

```
.login-form {
    max-width: 375px;
    background: black;
    padding: 25px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    /* -webkit-transform: translate(-50%,-50%); */
    -o-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    -moz-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
}
```

Is their any other method to center form for mobile as well as desktop in all major browsers like opera firefox chrome and safari? right now my code working fine with all except opera, I have webkit written for opera also. Please provide some suggestions. Thank you.

**Note** I have already tried with margin:0 auto; it centers only horizontally for vertical center I have to again adjust margin-top or padding-top which veries in browser to browser.

Comment: i think you should use `Media Queries` to center form in all browsers and mobile devices.

Comment: I could not find any error, it works perfectly fine on opera too.

Comment: here is an example **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mmushtaq/hABGX/109/)**

Comment: @frnt thanks for understanding me, actually it works fine with opera desktop but it failing in mobile devices that has lower version than kitkat. Its works great in 5 and more.

Comment: @user55 thanks for fiddle but its not center from top-bottom also the code is in table where as i have given you my code

Comment: @frnt thanks for understanding me, actually it works fine with opera desktop but it failing in mobile devices that has lower version than kitkat. Its works great in android 4.4.more, 5 and more.

Comment: @Sudarshan Kalebere you can edit media Queries according to your requirements. You can provide different media queries for different devices having different resolution and screen sizes.

Comment: media queries for opera? I have no need of media queries because its working fine in all browsers and mobile devices except opera lower veriosn than 5.

Comment: @SudarshanKalebere you can check browser compatibility on caniuse.com for your opera browser.

Comment: Transform property is not working fine with opera and uc browser same result instead of center its taking to right of mobile and it is only half visible, but in chrome safari working fine even in firefox

Answer (score 0):

This does not answer your question, but vendor-prefixed rules should be used in this order:

```
-ms-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
/* -webkit-transform: translate(-50%,-50%); */
-o-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
-moz-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
```

> Standard( Prefix free ) rules must come last, after all vendor-prefixed rules for a property.

Regarding your question, it seems to work fine on Opera. If it's not working properly on some older android versions, you may use [Modernizr](https://modernizr.com/) to detect what features are not supported in those versions and use css workarounds accordingly.

Comment: thank you for suggestion I know transform property is not working well in opera instead of making form in center it taking to right of screen

Comment: @SudarshanKalebere you can use negative `margin-left` for that particular browser then.

Comment: how to do it? I mean the only code I have in for all is what I posted in answer you can give me try their by making opera margin-left and trasform for all

Answer (score 0):

If need to have full page mask(backgroud) it can be done like:

css:

```
.login-form-section {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    overflow: auto;
    background: #fff;

    text-align: center;
}

.login-form-section:before {
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.login-form {
    max-width: 375px;
    background: black;
    padding: 25px;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: left;
    width: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The HTML

```
<div class="container"> 
                <div class="login-form-section">
                    <form class="login-form">
                        <h1 class="login-text">Login</h1>
                        <input type="email" class="input-lg form-control login-input" placeholder="Email" required="" autofocus="">
                        <input type="password" class="form-control login-input input-lg" placeholder="Password" required="">
                        <button class="btn btn-lg btn-yellow-submit btn-block" type="submit">
                        Login
                        </button>
                        <a class="forgot-pass-link" href="forgot-password.html"><span class="f-link">Forgot Password</span></a>
                        <a href="order.html" class="register-link"><span class="r-link">Register and Subscribe</span></a>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
```

and css is

```
    .login-form-section {
    width: 100%;
    background: black;
    position: relative;
    height: 200px;

}
.login-form{
  position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 20px 0;
  top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
  background: GRAY;
   -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
      -o-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
      -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
      -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
      transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
      text-align: center;


}
.login-form h1{margin: 0; margin-bottom: 10px;}
```

Comment: It not center at all.

Comment: I updated my css
.login-form-section {
    width: 100%;
    background: black;
    position: relative;
    height: 200px;

}
.login-form{
  position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 20px 0;
  top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
  background: GRAY;
   -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
      -o-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
      -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
      -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
      transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
      text-align: center;
      

}
.login-form h1{margin: 0; margin-bottom: 10px;}

Comment: Its not working @BirendraMaharjan I dont have problem with other browsers only opera I am facing problem
with your code I will face problems in all browsers please see my question, I need center of the screen, ie, from top-bottom left-right

Comment: Put the height of .login-form-section  is 100vh instated of 200px. I think this is work great.